# ListView cannot show after being invsibile during onCreate

Tags: android, listview

I have problem I want to hide the listVeiw during onCreate,but the problem is that when I hide my listview to invisible, the setOnTouchListener will not work.but if I remove `lstv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` before the setOnTouchListener, the setOnTouchListener is working,but I need to hide first my listview during start up or onCreate.

Thank you in advance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lstv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        vdo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                lstv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lstv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lstv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 3000);
                return true;
            }
        });


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vdo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/listview"
              android:layout_width="229dp"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:smoothScrollbar="true"
              android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"

             />

</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: Have you actually set your content view with setContentView? Like this:  setContentView(R.layout.yourFrameLayout);

Comment: instead of INVISIBLE use GONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hide ListView and receive onTouchEvent on `vdo`
You should change

```
lstv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to

```
lstv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the listview in the layout(xml) itself. Like this

```
 <ListView 
   ....
   ....
  android:visibility="gone"
  />
```